# New properties in advanced search are not appearing

Tags: 2010, search, search-results, refinement-panel

I am trying to add new properties to the advanced search, 5 new properties, I can see 3 but the other 2 I cant see them.

I tried also the property names in lowercase

This is a screenshot[image]

and here is the xml

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <LangDefs>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Arabic" LangID="ar"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Bengali" LangID="bn"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Bulgarian" LangID="bg"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Catalan" LangID="ca"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Simplified Chinese" LangID="zh-cn"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Traditional Chinese" LangID="zh-tw"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Croatian" LangID="hr"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Czech" LangID="cs"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Danish" LangID="da"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Dutch" LangID="nl"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="English" LangID="en"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Finnish" LangID="fi"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="French" LangID="fr"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="German" LangID="de"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Greek" LangID="el"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Gujarati" LangID="gu"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Hebrew" LangID="he"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Hindi" LangID="hi"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Hungarian" LangID="hu"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Icelandic" LangID="is"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Indonesian" LangID="id"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Italian" LangID="it"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Japanese" LangID="ja"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Kannada" LangID="kn"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Korean" LangID="ko"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Latvian" LangID="lv"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Lithuanian" LangID="lt"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Malay" LangID="ms"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Malayalam" LangID="ml"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Marathi" LangID="mr"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Norwegian" LangID="no"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Polish" LangID="pl"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Portuguese" LangID="pt"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Punjabi" LangID="pa"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Romanian" LangID="ro"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Russian" LangID="ru"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Slovak" LangID="sk"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Slovenian" LangID="sl"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Spanish" LangID="es"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Swedish" LangID="sv"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Tamil" LangID="ta"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Telugu" LangID="te"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Thai" LangID="th"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Turkish" LangID="tr"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Ukrainian" LangID="uk"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Urdu" LangID="ur"/>
    <LangDef DisplayName="Vietnamese" LangID="vi"/>
  </LangDefs>
  <Languages>
    <Language LangRef="en"/>
    <Language LangRef="fr"/>
    <Language LangRef="de"/>
    <Language LangRef="ja"/>
    <Language LangRef="zh-cn"/>
    <Language LangRef="es"/>
    <Language LangRef="zh-tw"/>
  </Languages>
  <PropertyDefs>
    <PropertyDef Name="Path" DataType="text" DisplayName="URL"/>
    <PropertyDef Name="Size" DataType="integer" DisplayName="Size (bytes)"/>
    <PropertyDef Name="Write" DataType="datetime" DisplayName="Last Modified Date"/>
    <PropertyDef Name="FileName" DataType="text" DisplayName="Name"/>
    <PropertyDef Name="Description" DataType="text" DisplayName="Description"/>
    <PropertyDef Name="Title" DataType="text" DisplayName="Title"/>
    <PropertyDef Name="Author" DataType="text" DisplayName="Author"/>
    <PropertyDef Name="DocSubject" DataType="text" DisplayName="Subject"/>
    <PropertyDef Name="DocKeywords" DataType="text" DisplayName="Keywords"/>
    <PropertyDef Name="DocComments" DataType="text" DisplayName="Comments"/>
    <PropertyDef Name="CreatedBy" DataType="text" DisplayName="Created By"/>
    <PropertyDef Name="ModifiedBy" DataType="text" DisplayName="Last Modified By"/>
    <PropertyDef Name="nlnmeetingyear" DataType="text" DisplayName="Year"/> 
    <PropertyDef Name="nlnmeetingtype" DataType="text" DisplayName="Meeting Type"/> 
    <PropertyDef Name="nlnagendapointcategory" DataType="text" DisplayName="Agenda point category"/>    
    <PropertyDef Name="NLNAgendaPointDecision" DataType="text" DisplayName="Agenda point decision"/>    
    <PropertyDef Name="NLNAgendaPointKeyword" DataType="text" DisplayName="Agenda point keywords"/>     
  </PropertyDefs>
  <ResultTypes>
    <ResultType DisplayName="All Results" Name="default">
      <KeywordQuery/>
      <PropertyRef Name="Author" />
      <PropertyRef Name="Description" />
      <PropertyRef Name="FileName" />
      <PropertyRef Name="Size" />
      <PropertyRef Name="Path" />
      <PropertyRef Name="Write" />
      <PropertyRef Name="CreatedBy" />
      <PropertyRef Name="ModifiedBy" />
      <PropertyRef Name="nlnmeetingyear" />  
      <PropertyRef Name="nlnmeetingtype" />  
      <PropertyRef Name="nlnagendapointcategory" />  
      <PropertyDef Name="NLNAgendaPointDecision" /> 
      <PropertyDef Name="NLNAgendaPointKeyword" />
    </ResultType>
    <ResultType DisplayName="Documents" Name="documents">
      <KeywordQuery>IsDocument="True"</KeywordQuery>
      <PropertyRef Name="Author" />
      <PropertyRef Name="DocComments"/>
      <PropertyRef Name="Description" />
      <PropertyRef Name="DocKeywords"/>
      <PropertyRef Name="FileName" />
      <PropertyRef Name="Size" />
      <PropertyRef Name="DocSubject"/>
      <PropertyRef Name="Path" />
      <PropertyRef Name="Write" />
      <PropertyRef Name="CreatedBy" />
      <PropertyRef Name="ModifiedBy" />
      <PropertyRef Name="Title"/>
    </ResultType>
    <ResultType DisplayName="Word Documents" Name="worddocuments">
      <KeywordQuery>FileExtension="doc" OR FileExtension="docx" OR FileExtension="dot" OR FileExtension="docm" OR FileExtension="odt"</KeywordQuery>
      <PropertyRef Name="Author" />
      <PropertyRef Name="DocComments"/>
      <PropertyRef Name="Description" />
      <PropertyRef Name="DocKeywords"/>
      <PropertyRef Name="FileName" />
      <PropertyRef Name="Size" />
      <PropertyRef Name="DocSubject"/>
      <PropertyRef Name="Path" />
      <PropertyRef Name="Write" />
      <PropertyRef Name="CreatedBy" />
      <PropertyRef Name="ModifiedBy" />
      <PropertyRef Name="Title"/>
    </ResultType>
    <ResultType DisplayName="Excel Documents" Name="exceldocuments">
      <KeywordQuery>FileExtension="xls" OR FileExtension="xlsx" OR FileExtension="xlsm" OR FileExtension="xlsb" OR FileExtension="ods"</KeywordQuery>
      <PropertyRef Name="Author" />
      <PropertyRef Name="DocComments"/>
      <PropertyRef Name="Description" />
      <PropertyRef Name="DocKeywords"/>
      <PropertyRef Name="FileName" />
      <PropertyRef Name="Size" />
      <PropertyRef Name="DocSubject"/>
      <PropertyRef Name="Path" />
      <PropertyRef Name="Write" />
      <PropertyRef Name="CreatedBy" />
      <PropertyRef Name="ModifiedBy" />
      <PropertyRef Name="Title"/>
    </ResultType>
    <ResultType DisplayName="PowerPoint Presentations" Name="presentations">
      <KeywordQuery>FileExtension="ppt" OR FileExtension="pptx" OR FileExtension="pptm" OR FileExtension="odp"</KeywordQuery>
      <PropertyRef Name="Author" />
      <PropertyRef Name="DocComments"/>
      <PropertyRef Name="Description" />
      <PropertyRef Name="DocKeywords"/>
      <PropertyRef Name="FileName" />
      <PropertyRef Name="Size" />
      <PropertyRef Name="DocSubject"/>
      <PropertyRef Name="Path" />
      <PropertyRef Name="Write" />
      <PropertyRef Name="CreatedBy" />
      <PropertyRef Name="ModifiedBy" />
      <PropertyRef Name="Title"/>
    </ResultType>
  </ResultTypes>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML is case-sensitive.  Change the case of 'NLNAgendaPointDecision' and 'NLNAgendaPointKeyword' to lower case so that it matches the three you can see

Comment: I changed both to lowercase and that doesnt make any difference, it still doesnt work.

Comment: You changed them to lower case in both PropertyDef and PropertyRef?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I'll add my answer anyway for future reference.

I believe that the the fields are not displayed correctly because the use of `PropertyDef`-tag inside the `ResultType`-tag. The correct tag would be `PropertyRef`.

So instead of this:

```
   <ResultType DisplayName="All Results" Name="default">
      <KeywordQuery/>
      ...
      <PropertyDef Name="NLNAgendaPointDecision" /> 
      <PropertyDef Name="NLNAgendaPointKeyword" />
   </ResultType>
```

You should have this:

```
   <ResultType DisplayName="All Results" Name="default">
      <KeywordQuery/>
      ...
      <PropertyRef Name="NLNAgendaPointDecision" /> 
      <PropertyRef Name="NLNAgendaPointKeyword" />
   </ResultType>
```